web3.py: How to get key from each generated multiple addresses (uses from_mnemonic()) but later
I generated multiple addresses from seed words uses from_mnemonic() method:
from web3 import Web3    
from eth_account import Account
    
def get_new_address(addr_number: int, mnemonic_words: str) -> str:
    Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
    acct = Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic_words, account_path=f"m/44'/60'/0'/0/{addr_number}")
    return acct.address

But, how can I get the key for each address to sign the transaction if I do not get it out at each new address and do not keep it anywhere for security? Can I somehow get it later when I need it for signing the transaction?
signed_txn = Account.sign_transaction(txn_data, key)
w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.raw_transaction)


You can retrieve the private key of an address (using acct.key.hex()) if you know the corresponding addr_number, like:
def get_private_key(addr_number: int, mnemonic_words: str) -> str:
    Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
    acct = Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic_words, account_path=f"m/44'/60'/0'/0/{addr_number}")
    return acct.key.hex()


what if the addr_number is not, only mnemonic_words and address from acct.address

You could possibly iterate the addr_number and match the acct.address.
